# How to tell my colleague to stop using racist language at work

Tags: professionalism, colleagues, conversation

I work in a large multinational company. My colleague uses a particular word for a greeting that is very offensive. It is not appropriate language at work and is against company policy.

My colleague used this racist language once with me before and I told them to stop. The offensive word was used while we were joking so they may not know I was serious.

I want to have a conversation with them about their choice of language. I've had conversations like this with close friends, but I'm not really sure what to say to a colleague. Any advice on how I can get them to understand this is a serious issue?

Note: we work in the same team, I do not report to them or have to work closely with them. They are generally an easy person to share an office with. I expect they will listen and be reasonable. I think it will be most effective if I have a conversation with them than escalate immediately to HR/management etc.

Comment: `My colleague uses a particular word for a greeting that is very offensive. It is not appropriate language at work and is against company policy.` according to ... you ?

Comment: @Walfrat: "is against company policy" - if it is written, and valid for this situation, then it is according to the company policy.

Comment: @SJX It would help a lot to know where (in the world) you work and what the word is and what leads you to believe that company policy prohibits it.

Comment: @Sonic this is what i'm asking, if it is really valid against company policy (checked with HR for instance) or on its own interpretation ?

Comment: @SJX: I think it is very important to the discussion to know what that word is? Maybe it is implied in your question, but I am not able to guess it. What is the word?

Comment: You don't *have a conversation* with someone. You *tell* you don't want to hear this. Maybe you add 'because I consider it ....', but these things are not worth a debate.

Comment: A particular word for a greeting? your going to have to say what this word is before we can help I cant think of an English greeting world that would be offensive?

Comment: I'm not convinced this question is a duplicate of the one identified. In the referenced question, he's talking about comments made about a third party, while in this question, she's talking about comments addressed to herself. I think strategies for dealing with these two cases might well be different.

Answer (score 9):

Try the informal approach first:

"Hey, you keep saying the word 'XXX', it's kind of offensive and I'd rather you didn't say it."

If that doesn't work, flag it to your boss.

Answer (score 4):

Just a gentle heads up just in case he doesn't realise how offensive you find it.

'You need to watch your mouth mate. It's not funny any more, it's just rude.'

Either that or grow thicker skin, it's only a word and you don't think it's meant maliciously.

But you don't have a dialogue or argument over it, just tell him you won't tolerate it.

Personally I just let people use whatever mannerisms they want to cultivate and only get upset by bigger things. Some people are showoffs, some people are rough around the edges or want to appear that way, others have strange hairstyles, others wear weird clothes, but so what?

Answer (score -2):

It's simple. You are having a "failure to communicate" problem due to the fact that his joking around is giving him a bubble to live in. You have to pierce that bubble by whatever it takes. Strip the make believe, strip the illusion.

1. Tell him again: "Look, I am dead serious. Your greeting is very offensive and against policy. I want you to stop. Immediately. You might think that what you're doing is joking around but I am not laughing."
2. Pause and await his reaction.
3. If he still not taking you seriously: "And if you continue, HR won't think you're laughing either. I am telling you this because this is our last chance to keep this between us".
4. And then, you follow through depending on what he decides to do.

Comment: This seems a bit "aggressive" to someone who might have no clue he was doing something wrong. I think talking to the person first and telling him it is offensive should suffice (Maybe even explain why it is). If that does not work, then you answer seems to be a good second conversation.

Comment: @Jeroen - You already told him that his greeting is very offensive. And you're still saying that he might have no clue what he is doing wrong? If that's the case, his next stop is HR where he can explain himself and where HR can use anything he says against him - I wouldn't waste any more time on this. It might be aggressive to you, but he is in a bubble and if you want to get your message through him, you're going to pierce a hole through that bubble. Quite a few who act like jerks don't see themselves as jerks. Until they are called out in a way that they can't ignore, downplay or dismiss.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan "he offensive word was used while we were joking so they may not know I was serious." that is what he said. So he is not sure if the person was aware he was serious.

Comment: @Jeroen - If I told you what I just wrote and you STILL don't think I am serious, your next stop is HR. You sort it out with them. Period. And if you want to be dismissed for cause, it's all up to you. I am not going to give myself a headache wondering what they'll do to you.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere - It's a threat only if he chooses to continue.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere - It's a threat only if he chooses to continue. Personally, this is how I threaten: first, I carry out the threat i.e. report him to HR. Second, I make the threat: "if you do it again, I am reporting you to HR". I almost never threaten, but I believe that any threat I make is not credible unless I have shown a track record of making good on my threats. The talk I am suggesting in the post is not a threat, he can still get out in one piece.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I don't see step 1 as a threat at all - its a direct statement & a request to change behavior and seems perfectly appropriate. Only at step 3 (after an  unsatisfactory response at step 2) does this 'escalate' to a threat - and at this point a threat of taking the issue to HR doesn't seem inappropriate.

Comment: Blatant threats like that can backfire in a big way.

Comment: I agree with this answer in part. It depends where you are and what the word was. But the part I agree with is that if someone is offending you, I don't see the point in being nice to them about it. Either laugh it off or tell them straight. I don't believe a person uses an offensive out of bounds greeting without knowing, But I'd leave out step 3 altogether and take it straight to HR or more direct action depending on his reaction.

Comment: @Kilisi "I don't believe a person uses an offensive out of bounds greeting without knowing". Some people get offended easily. However considering it is against the rules you could assume it is obvious. Then again the OP could be taking said rule way to broadly. We really do not know without knowing the greeting.

Comment: No, a threat is a threat. The whole point of a threat is that it is intended to pressure the other person into giving in. If I say, "If you don't stop doing X I will punch you in the face", that's a threat. If you do stop and I don't punch you in the face, then the threat achieved it's goal, but it was still a threat.

Comment: Without knowing what the word is that this person is using -- never mind knowing his background, mental state, etc -- it's impossible to say whether he knows or ought to know that it is offensive. Surely we've all heard people get offended at statements we thought totally innocuous.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan "It's a threat only if he chooses to continue." No, that's nonsense. Telling someone you will do something to them if they do/don't do something is the very _definition_ of a threat. Following through is retribution.

Comment: @William Kappler - I's not a threat, it's a promise that will be kept.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan The purpose of that saying is that it is worse than a threat, in that you have every intent of following through, not that it is no longer a threat.